# Neural networks 2nd edition

Tags: opencv, neural-network

Using opencv, I detect people's faces and put them in different folders. In the same folder faces of one person. Dimensions 200 200.

Now i need to identify a person. Installed php fann. In documentation to create a network

```
resource fann_create_standard ( int $num_layers    , 
                            int $num_neurons1  ,
                            int $num_neurons2 [, int $... ] )
```

I process the photos and taking color code

```
$my_example = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {

$dir = dir("teach/$i");

while($entry = $dir->read()) {
    if(!strstr($entry, 'png')) continue;

    $im = imagecreatefrompng("teach/$i/$entry");

    $cur_array = array();
    for($y=0; $y < 200; $y++) {
        for($x=0; $x < 200; $x++) {
            $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y) / 16777215;
            $cur_array[] = $rgb;
        }
    }

    imagedestroy($im);
    $my_example[] = array($cur_array, array($i));
}
}
```

How to create a network with what settings?

Thanks.